# Limit IIS rewrite map for particular domain

Tags: iis, url-rewriting, web-config, sitecore

My requirement is to redirect a URL for a particular domain. So, I decided to use a rewrite map, but what I tried below applies to all domains I have, not just to a particular domain.

Say I have 3 domains on the same IIS instance:

1. [www.abc.com](http://www.abc.com)
2. [www.xyz.com](http://www.xyz.com)
3. [www.eee.com](http://www.eee.com)

For domain **[www.abc.com](http://www.abc.com)** a URL **[www.abc.com/legal](http://www.abc.com/legal)** should be redirected to **[www.abc.com/privacy](http://www.abc.com/privacy)**.

Like for the above example, I have more redirects to be implemented for the same domain.

Here are things I tried so far:

```
   <!--Test snippet 1-->

    <rewrite>
      <rules>
        <rule name="Redirect rule1 for Redirects" enabled="true" stopProcessing="true">
          <match url=".*" />
          <conditions>
            <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern=".*www.abc.com.*" />
            <add input="{ABCRedirects:{REQUEST_URI}}" pattern="(.+)" />
          </conditions>
          <action type="Redirect" url="{C:1}" appendQueryString="false" /> 
        </rule>
      </rules>
      <rewriteMaps configSource="abc-rewritemaps.config" />
    </rewrite>

     <!--Test snippet 2-->
    <rewrite>
      <rules>
        <rule name="Redirect rule1 for Redirects" enabled="true" stopProcessing="true">
          <match url=".*www.abc.com.*" />
          <conditions>
            <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern=".*www.abc.com.*" />
            <add input="{ABCRedirects:{REQUEST_URI}}" pattern="(.+)" />
          </conditions>
          <action type="Redirect" url="{C:1}" appendQueryString="false" />
        </rule>
      </rules>
      <rewriteMaps configSource="abc-rewritemaps.config" />
    </rewrite>

     <!--Test snippet 3-->

    <rewrite>
      <rules>
        <rule name="Redirect rule1 for Redirects" enabled="true" stopProcessing="true">
          <match url=".*" />
          <conditions>            
            <add input="{ABCRedirects:{REQUEST_URI}}" pattern=".*www.abc.com.*" />
          </conditions>
          <action type="Redirect" url="{C:1}" appendQueryString="false" />
        </rule>
      </rules>
      <rewriteMaps configSource="abc-rewritemaps.config" />
    </rewrite>
    
    <!--My Rewrite map-->

    <rewriteMaps>
      <rewriteMap name="ABCRedirects">
        <add key="/legal" value="/privacy" />
        <add key="/good" value="/bad" />
        <add key="/hi" value="/bye" />
        <add key="/no" value="/not" />
        <add key="/123" value="/321" />
      </rewriteMap>
    </rewriteMaps>
```

The above settings always apply to all domains and I was not able to limit them to only one specific domain like `www.abc.com` for example.

How to limit rewrite maps for a particular domain?

Comment: I tested your first snippet and it worked for me. Can you try using failed request tracing to get a better understanding where it goes wrong, see here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/url-rewrite-module/using-failed-request-tracing-to-trace-rewrite-rules

Comment: @Jeroen ur idea helps, My code works actually.Due to iis caching its failed.